# Finding and retrieving consecutive matches

Tags: java, regex

Say I want to match a string that should solely consist of parts adhering to a specific (regex) pattern and retrieve the elements in a loop. For this it seems that [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) was invented. However, `find` will match any string, not just one that is directly after the pattern, so intermediate characters are skipped.

So - for instance - I want to match `\\p{Xdigit}{2}` (two hexadecimal digits) in such a way that:

- `aabb` matches;
- `_aabb` doesn't match;
- `aa_bb` doesn't match;
- `aabb_` doesn't match.

by using `find` (or any other iterated call to the regex) so I can directly process each byte in the array. So I want to *process* `aa` and `bb` separately, after matching.

OK, that's it, the most elegant way of doing this wins the accept.

---

Notes:

- the hexadecimal parsing is *just an example* of a simple repeating pattern;
- *preferably* I would like to keep the regex to the minimal required to match the element;
- yes, I know about using `(\\p{XDigit}{2})*`, but I don't want to scan string twice (as it should be usable on huge input strings).

Comment: if aabb is a word and not a partial word, why not use the word boundary?

Comment: @oldercoder I don't get that comment. This is about repetition of patterns, the whole idea of a word or word boundary doesn't come into the picture.

Comment: If you want to see if the whole string consists of repetitions of some pattern, you must use `matches()` and the pattern like you used, but wiht `+` quantifier, 1 or more repetitions. `s.matches("(?:xyz)+")`. You do not scan anything "twice", this is a single regex operation.

Comment: I wanted to use the matches of the pattern, remember? With `(?:X)` you're even removing the matches, and if you don't you'll still only have a single group to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to get all (multiple) matches that appear at the start of the string or right after a successful match. You may combine `\G` operator with a lookahead that will assure the string only matches some repeated pattern.

Use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:\p{XDigit}{2})*$))\p{XDigit}{2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GtCDLW/1)

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group with 2 alternatives:

  - `\G(?!^)` - the end of the previous successful match
  - `|` - or
  - `^(?=(?:\p{XDigit}{2})*$)` - start of a string (`^`) that is followed with 0+ occurrences of `\p{XDigit}{2}` pattern up to the end of the string (`$`)
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `\p{XDigit}{2}` - 2 hex chars.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/s3Sziy):

```
String regex = "(?:\\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*$))[0-9a-fA-F]{2}";
String[] strings = {"aabb","_aabb","aa_bb", "aabb_"}; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String s : strings) {
    System.out.println("Checking " + s);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        res.add(matcher.group(0));
    }
    if (res.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(res);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Checking aabb
[aa, bb]
Checking _aabb
No match!
Checking aa_bb
No match!
Checking aabb_
No match!
```

Comment: I'm trying to process the *separate* patterns, so `aa` and `bb`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes What do you mean by the comment above?

Comment: Oh, wait, never mind. I'll take another look. That's a complex regexp though. Wouldn't it process the whole string except the processed parts at every iteration?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Read the beginning of my answer: the regex checks (=validates) if the string only consists of some pattern repetitions (it is achieved with the positive lookahead), then these consecutive matches are returned only if the lookahead returned *true*.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I may finally have had a brainstorm: the idea is to remove the `find()` method *out of the condition of the while loop*. Instead I should simply keep a variable holding the location and only stop parsing when the whole string has been processed. The location can also be used to produce a more informative error message.

The location starts at zero and is updated to the end of the match. Each time a new match is found the start of the match is compared with the location, i.e. end of the last match. An error occurs if:

1. the pattern is not found;
2. the pattern is found, but not at the end of the last match.

Code:

```
private static byte[] parseHex(String hex){
        byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
        int off = 0;

        // the pattern is normally a constant
        Pattern hexByte = Pattern.compile("\\p{XDigit}{2}");
        Matcher hexByteMatcher = hexByte.matcher(hex);
        int loc = 0;
        // so here we would normally do the while (hexByteMatcher.find()) ...
        while (loc < hex.length()) {

            // optimization in case we have a maximum size of the pattern
            hexByteMatcher.region(loc, loc + 2);

            // instead we try and find the pattern, and produce an error if not found at the right location
            if (!hexByteMatcher.find() || hexByteMatcher.start() != loc) {
                // only a single throw, message includes location
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hex string invalid at offset " + loc);
            }
            // the processing of the pattern, in this case a double hex digit representing a byte value
            bytes[off++] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hexByteMatcher.group(), 16);

            // set the next location to the end of the match
            loc = hexByteMatcher.end();
        }

        return bytes;
 }
```

The method can be improved by adding `\\G` (end of last match) to the regex: `\\G\\p{XDigit}{2}`: this way the regular expression will fail immediately if the pattern cannot be found starting at the end of the last match or the start of the string).

For regular expressions with an expected maximum size (2 in this case) it is of course also possible to adjust the end of the region that needs to be matched.

Comment: It feels as if you only want to get matches that occur at the start of the string or the end of the preceding match. Why not use `Pattern.compile("\\G\\p{XDigit}{2}")` with `matcher.find()` in a while loop? If you need a whole string matching these patterns, `"(?:\\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:\\p{XDigit}{2})*$))\\p{XDigit}{2}"`

Comment: Oh, cool, that would probably be better than my `$` solution. What does `\G` do if there weren't any previous matches though?

Comment: `\G` matches either a start of string or end of the previous match.

Comment: Well, if that is an answer I will post it as a separate one.